# How to create a CLI in Python that can be installed with PIP?

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface

As the title suggests, I'm trying to make a python script accessible from the command line. I've found libraries like [click](https://pypi.org/project/click/) and [argv](https://pypi.org/project/argv/) that make it easy to access arguments passed from the command line, but the user still has to run the script through Python.

Instead of

```
python /location/to/myscript.py
```

I want to be able to just do

```
myscript
```

from any directory

From what I understand, I can achieve this on my computer by editing my PATH variables. However, I would like to be able to simply do:

```
pip install myscript
```

and then access the script by typing `myscript` from anywhere. Is there some special code I would put in the `setup.py`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with `setuptools`

an example of a nice `setup.py` (say your package requires pandas and numpy):

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='myscript',
    version='1.0',
    scripts=['./scripts/myscript'],
    author='Me',
    description='This runs my script which is great.',
    packages=['lib.myscript'],
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools',
        'pandas >= 0.22.0',
        'numpy >= 1.16.0'
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.5'
)
```

Your directory should be setup as follows:

```
[dkennetz package]$ ls
lib scripts setup.py
```

inside lib would be:

```
[dkennetz package]$ ls lib
myscript
```

inside of `myscript` would be:

```
[dkennetz package]$ ls lib/myscript
__main__.py
__init__.py
helper_module1.py
helper_module2.py
```

main would be used to call your function and do whatever you want to do.

inside scripts would be:

```
[dkennetz package]$ ls scripts
myscript
```

and the contents of `myscript` would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ! $@ ]]; then
    python3 -m myscript -h
else
    python3 -m myscript $@
fi
```

then to run you do: `python setup.py install`

which will install your program and all of the dependencies you included in `install_requires=[]` in your setup.py and install `myscript` as a command-line module:

```
[dkennetz ~]$ myscript
```

Comment: This lets me run the `myscript` command from the `myscript` folder, but from any other directory I get the error: `C:\Users\eleme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: No module named myscript`... I've followed the steps exactly, except instead of `lib/myscript/__main__.py` I have `myscript/__main__.py`

Comment: Then change setup.py in the packages section from lib.myscript to just myscript.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done but it still seems to not work. I'll give it another try following your instructions exactly when I get home

Comment: when you get home, check to see if there is an egg folder in your package directory. `python setup.py install` should make an egg. If that did not happen something else may not have worked. Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the same folder as the `__main__.py`?

Comment: Yep, everything works. In my case the problem was that my folder was called `MyScript` but the package name in `setup.py` was `myscript`. Thanks @d_kennetz

Comment: How do you make this compatible for windows and linux too? Do you just edit the bash script to detect what operating system you're running on?

Answer (score 26):

Use `console_scripts` to hook to a specific Python method (not a whole executable), `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['mybinary=mymodule.command_line:cli'],
    },
    name='mymodule',
    ...
)
```

the `command_line.py` script would be:

```
import mymodule

def cli():
    print("Hello world!")
```

and the project directory would look like this:

```
myproject/
    mymodule/
        __init__.py
        command_line.py
        ...
    setup.py
```

> Setuptools will generate a standalone script ‘shim’ which imports your module and calls the registered function.

That shim allows you to call `mybinary` directly and ensures it's correctly invoked by python. It provides platform-specific shims (i.e., on Windows it generates a .exe).

[See packaging documentation for more details](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html).

Comment: Make sure you also set `packages` (e.g., `packages=setuptools.find_packages(),`) so it installs the package that your generated script will use (`find_packages` optionally takes a top-level folder [and other args](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#using-find-or-find-packages)).

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is older and for a project using `setuptools` definitely use [Tombart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66010978/225020)

That said, I have been using poetry and that uses a `.toml` file and if that's what you use, and since this is likely what others will search for here's how you package a script with a toml file (*at least with poetry*)

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
myscript = "mybinary=mymodule.command_line:cli"
```

Not sure if this works for flit or any other package managers but it works for poetry

Comment: I think it is `[tool.poetry.scripts]` now:  https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in the bash shell and python 3 is installed and you want to be able to do what you are requesting, you will need to append the path of the script file to your PATH variable in your `.bash_profile` file in your home directory.  Also, in your python script file, you need to have something similar to the following as the first line of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Additionally, you can remove the extension (.py) from the script file, such that, as in my example above, the filename is a script in contrast to script.py.

You will also need to set the permission of your filename to

chmod 755 filename

If you want the script to be accessible system-wide, you will need to modify /etc/profile and add to the bottom of the file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/script
```

Alternatively, if you move the python script file to `/usr/local/bin`, it may not be necessary to make any profile changes as this directory is often already in the PATH.

To see the value of PATH issue the following command at the shell

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: It's a valid answer about *allow a script to be system-wide executed from shell*, however ignores completely the *can be installed with PIP* part, and therefore does not answer the question