# Create a python package and after install use like a executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging, python-wheel

I am working on a script and I would like to use like an executable.
That means I wanna install with pip and run with its name.
example:

```
pip install myscript.whl
myscript
```

I am already created a whl file (via 'python setup.py bdist_wheel'), however I am not sure what is the next step.
How can I do that after pip install an executable automatically created and can be used from anywhere in powershell or linux terminal.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: This is my answer from awhile ago, but it is a decent way to build out a package with an executable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56534786/8468264

Comment: @d_kennetz The shell-based script in your answer won't work with Windows environments -- `console_scripts` will...

Comment: Oh true! @AKX, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have a `setup.py`, all you need to do is follow the [steps outlined in the Packaging Guide](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) to set up a console script entry point.

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['myscript=myscript.some_module:some_function'],
    }
    ...
```