# How to create multiple CLI options identified my package name in a python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a cli interface for my application which has nested functionality. Example:

```
├── ...
├── setup.py
└── package-name
    ├──__init__.py
    ├──command1.py
    └──command2.py
```

```
package-name command1 --arg .. ..
package-name command2 --arg ..
```

AND

```
python -m package-name command1 --arg ..
```

The thing to note here is that `command1` and `command2` are independent modules that accept different command-line args. So linking them together in a `__main__.py` might also be another challenge.

I came across similar questions that use `entry_points` in `setup.py` to create similar cli functionality but its not exactly what I'm looking for. I found this similar question.
[How to create a CLI in Python that can be installed with PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534678/how-to-create-a-cli-in-python-that-can-be-installed-with-pip)

Comment: did you take a look at the argparse module?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: @alexpdev both modules use argparse. My doubt is how to link both(or more) functionalities in a single `__main__.py` inside the package so they can be accessed via `python -m pack-name`
Maybe I didn't ask the question clearly. I can try to clarify

Comment: oh so your saying you want one cli to access multiple sub-cli's?

Comment: @alexpdev yep exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want access multiple sub-cli's in one entry command, you can implement a sub-command manager at `__main__.py`, which can parse sub-command from sys.argv and then dispatch to target module.

1️⃣First, i recommend the [google fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/guide.md), which can satify you in most scenarios without extra code.

Here is a example, you can replace the add/multiply function to your sub-command function by using `from command1 import xx`，and use entry points to expose the main function.

```
import fire

def add(x, y):
  return x + y

def multiply(x, y):
  return x * y


def main():
  fire.Fire({
      'add': add,
      'multiply': multiply,
  })

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

We can debug this in the same way as below:

```sh
$ python example.py add 10 20
30
$ python example.py multiply 10 20
200
```

2️⃣Second, if you need implements by your self for some purpose, such as using argparse to define options for each command. A typical practice is the [Django command](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/management/base.py#L173), the official demo: [Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/)

The core steps is :

1. define a BaseCommand
2. implements BaseCommand in sub commands.py, and named it as `Command`.
3. `__main__.py` implements find command and call

```py
# base_command.py
class BaseCommand(object):
    def create_parser(self, prog_name, subcommand, **kwargs):
        """
        Create and return the ``ArgumentParser`` which will be used to
        parse the arguments to this command.
        """
        # TODO: create your ArgumentParser
        return CommandParser(**kwargs) 
        
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        """
        Entry point for subclassed commands to add custom arguments.
        """
        pass

    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        """
        Entry point for commands to be run from the command line.
        """
        parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
        options = parser.parse_args(argv[2:])
        cmd_options = vars(options)
        args = cmd_options.pop('args', ())
        self.handle(*args, **cmd_options)
    
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """
        The actual logic of the command. Subclasses must implement
        this method.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of BaseCommand must provide a handle() method')
    
    
# command1.py     
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print("Hello, it is command1!")
        
   
# command2.py     
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print("Hello, it is command2!")
        
    
# __main__.py         
def main():
    # sub command name is the second argument
    command_name = sys.argv[1]
    # build sub command module name, and import
    # package-name is the module name you mentioned
    cmd_package_name = f'package-name.{command_name}'
    instance = importlib.import_module(cmd_package_name)
    # create instance of sub command, the Command must exist
    command = instance.Command()
    command.run_from_argv(sys.argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your answer works well! But on running `cli-command --help`, it opens some sort of shell editor window to display helper string and I have to `ctrl+Z` to exit. Any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: This is a feature of Fire, and can not turn off. It will always append  `less` or `pager` to your command when showing help text，like the `man python` command behavior,.  You can type `q` to exit.

Comment: Ohh okay. But this also happens after a command executes? I'm seeing that after a command executes a similar page is opened providing description of whatever command was executed

Comment: No，it will use print function for command execute. But when it can not recognize the command ouput, it will give the help text which will lead to less behavior.

Comment: So I'm seeing this output screen every time a command executes successfully https://imgur.com/a/7pfmzis . Can I get rid of this somehow?

Comment: It looks a help view.  I think you can debug it, the behavor is implement by `Display` function.
1. step into fire.Fire function, and find the  _PrintResult call , all Display before _PrintResult will only called when --help or --trace flag was set.
2. then step into _PrintResult function
3. find out why it step to last else branch which will print help by Display.

Comment: Okay thanks for pointing me there. I just patched the `_PrintResult`function to do nothing because I don't really want it to print anything.